# What is the optimal number of clusters when using doParallel in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a process to parallelize with a "for" that iterates 15 times. I've done it this way thanks to `doParallel` package:

```
cl<-makeCluster(15)
registerDoParallel(cl)
ptime <- system.time({
table_all <- foreach (ii = 1:length(dates), .combine=rbind) %dopar% { 
     function_exemple(dates[ii], table_part) ## returns table_part
     table_part
}
})[3]
cat(ptime)
```

I have 32 cores running on a Windows server. In this case I found that 15 clusters worked much better than trying to use 32. Does anybody knows the reason? Also my next question would be: When I have more than 32 iterations, (i.e, 50, 1000). What should be the correct number of clusters to register? Maybe a number multiple of 32?

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is strange. What does `table_all` do in there?

Comment: Also, normally you'd register as many CPUs as you want to use and are available. Memory can be an issue there. If you have 32 CPUs you cannot use more than that and would usually leave some for other processes on the server.

Comment: Thanks @Roland for your quick answer. I've edited the code because as you said it was weird as I did not copy it correctly. I have a function that takes quite a long time to create  `table_part` . Once create all them in  parallel thanks to `foreach` I join them with rbind to create `table_all` .Hope now it is more clear.